# NativeScript: How to overlay one component over another

Tags: nativescript

I want to develop NativeScript-Angular Mobile App as the screenshot below:

But I'm unable to hover the settings box over the existing component on the page.

Since settings dropbox is part of action bar under Header component and below that is another component with a image which covers the entire space available on page.

The Setting dropbox is a StackLayout in header component and so is the component with image for the entire page.

Answer (score 2):

**How to overlay one component over another**

You can use a GridLayout and assign the same row/column to the two components

Comment: At the app component, I have this code 
<StackLayout>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
while the action bar is in app-header wrapped inside another stacklayout

Comment: The GridLayout should be the super parent that will hold your dropbox and stack layout with router outlet.